# How do I change the colour of an SVG shape using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

**Hi, folks! New here! Hoping to contribute a fair amount to the community in the future. But first, I need a hand with something I imagine to be fairly simple!**

I've always been all about the design aspect of the web, so mainly concentrated on HTML and CSS. I've only recently started looking in to learning JavaScript/jQuery, so bear with me, haha!

I'm having a little trouble with changing the colour of an SVG shape using jQuery. The basic idea is that when the user scrolls down the page, certain elements will change colour. The HTML elements change as expected, but the SVG properties don't. I've read something about SVG DOM being different to HTML DOM, but can't really make much sense of it? A small explanation along with any help wouldn't be ignored!

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<header>
    <div id="headercontainer">
        <object id="logo" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/kennyheardlogo.svg"></object>
        <nav><a id="homelink" href="index.html">HOME</a> | <a id="aboutlink" href="index.html">ABOUT</a> | <a id="worklink" href="index.html">WORK</a> | <a id="sociallink" href="index.html">SOCIAL</a></nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.headerfade {
    background-color: #000000;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;  
    right: 40px;
    width: 480px;
    height: auto;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

nav, nav a {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.navfade {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

#icon {
    fill: #000000;
}

.iconfade {
    fill: #ffffff;
}

#letterk, #letterh {
    fill: #ffffff;
}

#text path {
    fill: #000000;
}
```

**Here is my jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 350) {
        $("header").addClass("headerfade");
        $("nav, nav a").addClass("navfade");
        $("#icon").addClass("iconfade");
    } else {
        $("header").removeClass("headerfade");
        $("nav, nav a").removeClass("navfade");
        $("#icon").removeClass("iconfade");
    }
});
```

The initial colour of "#icon" is *black*, but when the user scrolls 350px from the top of the page, I want the colour to change to *white*. That is what I have done with the "header" and "nav" elements, which worked perfectly. So, any ideas?

**I'm hoping I've not missed something embarrassingly obvious, haha!**

**Thanks for any help you can provide, guys!**

Comment: So add / removeClass works for header and nav when you scroll down but doesn't work for #icon? Have you checked the class is added to #icon when you scroll down?

Comment: Exactly, yeah- it doesn't work for #icon. I've checked using Safari's JavaScript profiler, and the class is added to header and nav, but not to #icon within the SVG file.

Comment: i think the issue is you're using an `object` element rather than an `svg` element. try taking all of the `svg` code and placing that into the DOM

Comment: Try $("#icon").attr("class", "iconfade") for adding the class and $("#icon").attr("class", "") for removing the class

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these solutions seem to work? I'm pretty sure I'm implementing them correctly too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong here.

1. You can't directly access the contents of an `<object>` like that.  You need to get the `contentDocument` and access it that way.
2. CSS doesn't work across document boundaries.  Even once you add the `iconfade` class to `#icon`, it won't be able to see it because the CSS is in a different document.

What you can do is inline the SVG file in your HTML.  It should work then.

Comment: Hmm, OK. Does it not matter that I've linked the CSS document with the SVG document? Also, using inline SVG doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Played with this some more. You're absolutely right about the CSS not being able to talk to the SVG document. Using inline SVG didn't work initially, but I changed the CSS selector "#icon" to "path #icon", and it worked perfectly. The colour changed as expected!

My only issue is, the SVG code is pretty long. It's a headache in amongst the HTML. Is there anyway to do this with an external SVG document?

Comment: You didn't provide the SVG, so I couldn't tell what was in it.

Comment: Have you tried putting the style inside the svg? i.e. <svg ...>
  <style>
    /* SVG specific fancy CSS styling here */
  </style>
  ...
</svg> [link](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)